# Web store version control for very small group or individual?

Tags: version-control

For very small teams, or an individual developer, is there a source code control tool which is a web service, or web based application, with no or very little cost?

Ideally, it would work with Microsoft development. IDE Integration would be awesome, but a windows application that connects to the web service would also be sufficient.

Would you consider such a product to be market worthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend [Codespaces](http://www.codespaces.com/). It has a free plan, and the next plan up is only $3/mo. It comes with project planning and a bunch of goodies. Look at the screenshots page, pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is free if you OpenSource the project and is only $7/month for personal plans.
http://github.com/plans

I don't know much about it's possible IDE integration, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Unfuddle.co](http://unfuddle.com/)m for subversion or [Github](http://github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be ads on this site for [BeanStalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/).  Free for a single repository/3 users.  There are a few tools to integration SVN with an IDE - try [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/).